# Type constraints for polymorphic functions like lift

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monad-transformers, type-constraints, lifting

So I have this code

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import MonadA

data A = A

newtype MonadA a => MyStateT a b { runMyStateT :: StateT A a b }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadState A)

instance MonadTrans MyStateT where
    lift = MyStateT . lift
```

and I get the compiler complaining that it cannot prove the `m` from signature of `lift` is of type `MonadA` or thats how I read these cryptic error messages.

```
Could not deduce (MonadA m) arising from a use of `MyStateT'
from the context (Monad m)
  bound by the type signature for
             lift :: Monad m => m a -> MyStateT m a
```

is there a way to deal with this? I think I need the constraint to be able to instantiate as follows:

```
instance MonadA a => MonadA (MyStateT a) where
    f = MyStateT . lift . f
```

Also would such an implementation of `f` work? (I did not get that far due to the above error). I hope `f` on the right side to resolve to `f` over the inner monad `a`.

---

**Edit**: It indeed helped to drop the type constraint in `newtype MonadA a => MyStateT ...` to avoid the exact error that I mentioned. However there was just another error which I previously attributed to the same thing, consider this continuation of the example code above (some parts are repeated, now without type constraints):

```
class MonadB m where
    fB :: m ()

newtype MyStateT m a = MyStateT { runMyStateT :: StateT A m a}
    deriving (... MonadState A ...)

instance MonadTrans MyStateT where
    lift = MyStateT . lift

instance MonadA a => MonadA (MyStateT a) where
    f = lift . f

instance MonadA a => MonadB (MyStateT a) where
    fB = lift (modify (...))
```

the error is

```
Could not deduce (a ~ StateT A m0) from context (MonadA (MyStateT a), MonadA a)
```

in the implementation of `fB`. Earlier I tried `class MonadA m => MonadB m` to no avail. It doesn't even make sense to be matching `a` with `StateT A m`. Since `MyStateT` is an instance of `MonadState A` it should work, no?

**Edit**:

OK, got it working:

```
fB = MyStateT (modify ...)
```

stupid me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is dropping the constraint from the `MyStateT` definition:

```
newtype MyStateT a b { runMyStateT :: StateT A a b }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadState A)
```

Datatype constraints are essentially useless, as you need to put them in the function signatures anyway. For that reason, that feature is actually [deprecated](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html).

> I think I need the constraint to be able to instantiate as follows:

Not really; `instance MonadA a => MonadA (MyStateT a)` will work just fine without it.

> Also would such an implementation of `f` work?

It will. Note that, as you provided a `MonadTrans` instance for `MyStateT`, you don't actually need to wrap with `MyStateT` explicitly:

```
instance MonadA a => MonadA (MyStateT a) where
    f = lift . f
```